VBA basic loop to read in and add numbers in array
I have a large excel of purchase orders where i need to add all the quantities of unique part numbers. I am trying to search the entire excel file, and add the quantities if they are a specific part number.
Example:



Part Number
QTY




364
7


364
11


373
6


373
8


373
54


334
8


334
2



I want to be able to create a function with the part number and all data as an input that spits out the total for selected part number. For example, if i wanted to find the total quantity of 364 i would type into excel:
QtyPerPN(364, A2:B8) would return 18.
How do i make the QtyPerPN() function correctly?
    Function QtyPerPN(PartNumber, PN_QTYRange() As Variant)

     Dim TotalQty, counter
     TotalQty = 0
     counter = 0
   
     Dim i As Long
     i = 0
   
     Do While counter < 15
     '15 is just for testing on small set amount of data
        counter = counter + 1
            If PartNumber = PN_QTYRange(i) Then
                TotalQty = TotalQty + PN_QTYRange(i, i)
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Loop

     QtyPerPN = TotalQty
    
    End Function


What need is there for a custom function here... why not just use SUMIF()? If you really want to use VBA, you can just write Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf().

Put the function in a module.
Function QtyPerPN(PartNumber As Long, PN_QTYRange As Range)
    QtyPerPN = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(PN_QTYRange.Columns(1), PartNumber, PN_QTYRange.Columns(2))
End Function

